# How restrict A cookie associated with a cross-site resource?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-3, bootstrap-4, echarts

I am getting the following error after login into the website.My website header,side menu whole dashboard  design all looking badly.I don't know why this error is coming.I used echarts baidu in my dashboard and site is worked these many days without any fail.

I viewed in the browser console showing the following error.where as in other browsers also site is not working.

A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://cloudflare.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

Please suggest me how to fix this error.